# Semi-responsive background image without using background-image/background-size property

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a better solution for creating a full-screen, semi-responsive background image without using the background-image/background-size CSS properties.  It's a long story, but that's the requirement.

More specifically, I'm looking for a solution to automatically center this image (vertically and horizontally) within a container regardless of screen size and a pure CSS solution would be preferable over a jQuery/javascript one.

The HTML/CSS below accomplishes the first part, but with the "max-height" and "overflow:hidden" properties, it's a little wonky, it's very dependent on the image/screen size and doesn't leave a lot of flexibility in the image choice.

```css
#banner.subpageBanner {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#banner.subpageBanner>.bgContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#banner.subpageBanner>.bgContainer>img.subpageBG {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner" class="subpageBanner">
  <!-- Banner BG Image Container -->
  <div class="bgContainer">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" class="subpageBG" alt="">
  </div>
  <!-- Banner Heading Content -->
  <div class="inner">
    <header class="major">
      <h1>A Big, Bold Heading</h1>
    </header>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you clarify further? In the event where you have an image not large enough to occupy the full screen size what would be the desired outcome?

Comment: That's the issue.  The desired outcome is to ensure the image covers the entire banner and is centered in the container, regardless of screen size or orientation.  Having the edges of said image overflowing and hidden is fine.

Perhaps I use a couple of media queries to adjust width:100% on desktop screen sizes and height:100% on mobile.

Comment: If that is the desired outcome at all times (and screens resolutions) declaring `height: 100%` initially on `subpageBG`, instead of `auto`, will not require any further rules to be declared for mobile resolutions. To maintain a high quality image standard a high resolution will be required, defining `srcset` with various alternative resolutions will enable the user agent (browser) to make the best selection, from the provided source options, for the given resolution or bandwidth of the end-user at the time. **see:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset

Comment: If I understand correctly, You can use display:flex; for bgContainer with  justify-content: center; align-items: center; so your image will be centered vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yeah. That was actually the first thing I did and it works until I got on the widescreen monitor. If I heavily edit the image aspect ratio ahead of time, I got it to work in most use cases, but it was still pretty wonky... especially when then switching back to a mobile device.

Comment: @u238.  That’s not a bad suggestion for the centering. Not sure without playing some more how that’ll work with the aspect ratios.  I think I’m going to have to work a JavaScript solution.